# Wrong x-axis position and formatting when only 1 data series sent to chart

Tags: highcharts

I found out a problem with chart (highcharts 2.3.5) when i enter datetime series with only 1 data entry, it renders it with incorrect placement on x-axis and wrong point formatting.

here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/LAcSw/

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9]
        ]
    }]
  });
});
```

Is there a fix know or something(it was fine on 2.2.5)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have a single point HighCharts is making its best guess as to the yAxis range as well as what the label is on the point for the xAxis.
You are not defining any sort of formatting for the xAxis datetime labels - and HighCharts only has one point to work with so it defaults to time. If you assign a [`formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter) for the xAxis labels you can get it to do what you want.

Here is some rough code to show you what this does:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d %b %Y', this.value);
        }
    }
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max:50
},
```

And here is your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/xu5e2/) updated.